# Not able to delay between displaying icons

Tags: java, timing

When the actionPerformed method is invoked I would like it to display the desired icon on the first button, delay for 1 second and then display the icon on the second button. The icons always display simultaneously?  Not sure how to correct this.

```
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        btnTest1.setIcon(img2);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        btnTest2.setIcon(img2);
    }
```

Comment: Check you logcat. Are you getting any message from `e1.printStackTrace();`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for JavaFX / Java Swing. I'm not too familiar with it, but I believe the threads aren't working is because there are concurrency rules related to using threads in swing apps. I've had similar issues and wrote a question about how to delay something using threads. I found sources for using a `timer` object. It might be better to implement the timer by doing:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

I'm sure other more advanced users may give more detail. This is maybe another option. Oracle might help too:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

The buttons' icons are set with `setIcon`, but that doesn't mean they are painted immediately. Both icons will only be painted after you return from your `actionPerformed` method. What you need to do is set the icon for the first button, then use `Timer` (see [zOrigin_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432233/13963086)) and after the timer elapses, set the second button's icon.